# Formula or graph for decreasing percent change when a constant is added to variables

Tags: percentages

If the title doesn't make sense I will try to explain via example.

There were 100 apples, 80 were purchased; 80% were purchased
Add 100 to each, apples and purchases
200 apples, 180 purchased; 90% were purchased
300 apples, 280 purchased; 93.33% were purchased
etc. 
Is there a formula/rule that can be applied which will show the relationship of the values?

I guess what I mean is, is there a rule governing by what increment the % purchased will change for each increment of 100 apples? 
What if it were 60 apples?

Comment: Maybe assign some letters to the quantities like :  $N$ apples, $n$ purchased, then add $k$ to both variables : $N+k$ apples, $n+k$ purchased. Calculate percentage and see how it grows. If you're familair with calculus, this tells everything :  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim_%7Bk%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D+%28%5Cdfrac%7Bn%2Bk%7D%7BN%2Bk%7D%5Ctimes+100%29